# PySpark first and last function over a partition in one go

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have pyspark code like this,

```
spark_df = spark_df.orderBy('id', 'a1', 'c1')
out_df = spark_df.groupBy('id', 'a1', 'a2').agg(
    F.first('c1').alias('c1'),
    F.last('c2').alias('c2'),
    F.first('c3').alias('c3'))
```

I need to keep the data ordered in the order id, a1 and c1. Then select columns as shown above over the group defined over the keys id, a1 and c1.

Due to first and last non-determinism I changed the code to this ugly looking code which works but I'm not sure that is efficient.

```
w_first = Window.partitionBy('id', 'a1', 'a2').orderBy('c1')
w_last = Window.partitionBy('id', 'a1', 'a2').orderBy(F.desc('c1'))

out_first = spark_df.withColumn('Rank_First', F.rank().over(w_first)).filter(F.col('Rank_First') == 1).drop(
    'Rank_First')
out_last = spark_df.withColumn('Rank_Last', F.rank().over(w_last)).filter(F.col('Rank_First') == 1).drop(
    'Rank_Last')

out_first = out_first.withColumnRenamed('c1', 'First_c1') \
    .withColumnRenamed('c2', 'First_c2') \
    .withColumnRenamed('c3', 'First_c3')

out_last = out_last.withColumnRenamed('c1', 'Last_c1') \
    .withColumnRenamed('c2', 'Last_c2') \
    .withColumnRenamed('c3', 'Last_c3')

out_df = out_first.join(out_last, ['id', 'a1', 'a2']) \
    .select('id', 'a1', 'a2', F.col('First_c1').alias('c1'),
            F.col('Last_c2').alias('c2'),
            F.col('First_c3').alias('c3'))
```

I was trying for a better and efficient alternative. I run in to bottle necks in performance when data size is huge.

Is there a better alternative to do first and last over a window ordered in a specific order in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `orderBy` with Window you need to specify frame boundaries as `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` otherwise the `last` function will only get last value between `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` and `CURRENT ROW` (the default frame bounds when order by is specified).

Try this:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id', 'a1', 'a2').orderBy('c1') \
          .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = df.withColumn("First_c1", first("c1").over(w)) \
      .withColumn("First_c3", first("c3").over(w)) \
      .withColumn("Last_c2", last("c2").over(w))

df.groupby("id", "a1", "a2")\
  .agg(first("First_c1").alias("c1"),
       first("Last_c2").alias("c2"),
       first("First_c3").alias("c3")
  ).show()
```

Comment: I'm still getting varying results when by data for a partition is too huge. Any fix for this?