# Spark: Are first and last aggregate functions deterministic when used on a Window?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The [PySpark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.last) says that first() and last() functions of Spark are non-deterministic (without mentioning the use "inside" of windows) ; while doing some research on this, i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151709/pyspark-first-and-last-function-over-a-partition-in-one-go) that states:

> You could still use last and first functions over a Window which guarantees determinism

So, are first and last deterministic when used over a Window and non-deterministic when used on a Group? Is there some documentation confirming this?

Comment: Hi, I was having the issue with last(), where once a while it was giving wrong result, did you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation supporting this, but this is just from my experience:

`first` and `last` are deterministic only if the `Window` has a well-defined ordering. There has to be an `orderBy` clause in the `WindowSpec` definition, and also the ordering has to be unique, i.e. no two rows should have the same value in the column being ordered by.

Answer (score 0):

MCK's answer is right, because the underlying tables being queried have no explicit ordering in Spark.

In order to make these functions deterministic, you need to make sure to use an `ORDER BY` clause that is unique. I usually include the table's `PK` as a final tiebreaker in my `ORDER BY` clauses to ensure deterministic results.

This thread has more in-depth answers for a similar window function:
[Is ORDER BY and ROW_NUMBER() deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613055/is-order-by-and-row-number-deterministic)